# Flickering CSS animation on IE only

Tags: debugging, cross-browser, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, flicker

I have following code running fine on modern browsers, except IE11 :

A simple pseudo-element animated to rotate indefinitely.

```css
@keyframes spin{
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin{
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spin-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  

.spin-container::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) green green rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: calc(50% - 50px);
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin-container"></div>
```

I've been looking for a reason for weeks now, and I cannot determinate a property that can cause this.

I first suspected a transform-origin to not be the center of my pseudo-element spinner, but it appears that default value is `50% 50% 0` for every browser.

Then I looked into z-axis modification, or crazy inheritance, but I definitely found nothing.

Does anyone know why this flickers on IE11, and not on other browsers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 has some issues related to hardware acceleration and CSS animation:

- [IE 11 Leaving Artifacts and not redrawing screen](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/808481)
- [CSS Transition Property not working for SVG Elements](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/920928/ie-11-css-transition-property-not-working-for-svg-elements)

Microsoft is only fixing security related issues in IE11, so this will most likely remain unfixed.